# initializing a set in cplex/opl

Tags: javascript, cplex, opl

i am currently working on establishing a negotiation between a buyer and a supplier on basis of the multi-capacitated lot sizing problem, implemented in cplex.
in a small scenario, the buyer is producing items 1-4, whereas the supplier is responsible for supplying items 5-7.

what i want to do is create three sets:

```
{int} buyeroperations

{int} supplieroperations

{int} operations = buyerops union supplierops
```

my question now, as i am fairly new to cplex/opl, is how to initialize the sets with the respective items in order to work with them in my models.
i guess i could initialize them internally by means of:

```
{int} buyeroperations = asSet(1..4) 

{int} supplieroperations = asSet(5..7) 

{int} operations = buyeroperations union supplieroperations
```

am i correct?
could i however initialize the sets differently via script and a for loop?

so as said,ultimately i want three sets with the first four items being assigned to buyeroperations, items 5-7 being assigned to supplieroperations and then a set operations regarding all of them.

thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate out the model and data file to make things easier. 
In the model file, I will have:

```
{int} buyeroperations = ...;
{int} supplieroperations = ...;
{int} operations = buyeroperations union supplieroperations;
```

In the data file, I will have:

```
buyeroperations = [1,2,3,4] // same as [1..4]
supplieroperations = [5,6,7] // same as [5..7]
```

If there is a lot of data, the best way to initialize sets is with a database. What you showed should work as well.